# React module not found. Error: Cannot find file: 'LeftNav.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\pages\shared\leftNav\leftnav'

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

Can not import react components. The header and Footer components were imported without any error or difficulty. But after creating the LeftNav and RightNav components, this error has been occuring. I have double checked the paths on code and localdisk. But still can't figure out where this error is originating from.

vscode and error image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Umfg.png)

component on local disk (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJoli.png)

I have tried restarting and clearing vscode cache.

Answer (score 3):

you was a typo

you using leftNav/LeftNav

the correct is
leftnav/LeftNav

try

```
import LeftNav from "../pages/shared/leftnav/LeftNav"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very careless of me.